# Advice on plotting two populations over time

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Basically I've created a plot which shows the distributions of two populations 10 every 10 years, but I've realised it's not really clear at all to someone looking which year is which line on the graph - my actual code is all fine, but I was wondering if anyone had any advice on how to show clearly which lines are t=10, 20 etc and so on. I'll include my code for anyone interested. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import random
from math import sqrt
%matplotlib inline

r1=0.1 # growth rate B
r2=0.3 # growth rate M
KB=20 # carrying capacity B
x=np.arange(0,70) # position
dx=1 # distance step
m=71 # number of distance steps
alpha =  0.00002 # predation rate of M on B
beta=0 # growth rate M from eating B
KM=71*[] # carrying capacity M
KM[0:71]=4000+(4000/2)*(1+np.cos(np.pi*x/35))
n=101 # years
dt=1 # time step

B=np.zeros(shape=(m,n)) # B
M=np.zeros(shape=(m,n)) # M
D=0.35 # diffusivity of B
D2=0.05 # diffusivity of M
Alpha=(D*dt)/(dx*dx) # diffusion term for the B
Alpha2=(D2*dt)/(dx*dx) # diffusion term for the M

M[0,0]=0
M[m-1,0]=0
B[1:m-1,0]=5
M[1:26,0]=2500
M[26:44,0]=1000 # initial conditions
M[44:m-1,0]=2500
for k in range(0,n-1):
    B[0,k+1]=B[1,k+1]
    B[m-1,k+1]=B[m-2,k+1] # boundary conditions
    M[0,k+1]=0
    M[m-1,k+1]=0
    for i in range(1,m-1):
        B[i,k+1]=(1-2*Alpha)*B[i,k]+Alpha*B[i+1,k]+Alpha*B[i-1,k]+r1*B[i,k]*(1-B[i,k]/KB)-alpha*M[i,k]*B[i,k] # 
        M[i,k+1]=(1-2*Alpha2)*M[i,k]+Alpha2*M[i+1,k]+Alpha2*M[i-1,k]+r2*M[i,k]*(1-M[i,k]/KM[i])+beta*M[i,k]*B[i,k]
    if (k+1) % 10 == 0 or k==0:
        plt.plot(B[:,k],color='b') 
        plt.plot(M[:,k]/1000,color='r')

plt.xlabel('Position')
plt.ylabel('Density per 10 ha')
plt.title('Distributions of the B and M population every 10 years \n - with equilibrium distribution of B')
speciesM = mpatches.Patch(color='r', label='M (1000)')
speciesB = mpatches.Patch(color='b', label='B')
plt.legend(handles=[speciesM,speciesB])
```

[image]

Comment: Create a list of line styles and then zip that together with the loop that's plotting? https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/line_styles_reference.html Alternatively, using `plt.subplots`, you can create a separate graph in the same figure for each separate line.

Comment: How about something like [this](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#polygon-plots), but plotting only the outlines and then plotting both red and blue for each time slice?